# create long table within multiple pages

Tags: longtable

need to create long table within multiple pages.My code gives 3 errors "Error: Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\renewcommand): `c' used." and
"Error: Misplaced \noalign. " and "Error: Misplaced \omit.'"   my code is,

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}


 \FloatBarrier
 \begin{longtable}[!ht]
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
 \caption[Test Cases for Login Subsystem]{Test Cases for Login Subsystem}
 \label{Test Cases for Login Subsystem}\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
 \toprule
 \bfseries Test Objective/Scenario & \bfseries Function & \bfseries Input & \bfseries Expected Outcome\\ \midrule
 Login   & Login function  & Insert dfdgfd ffgfgfgdfg \& dfgdfgdf fdgfg gf gfgfg fdgdfgdfgdfgf \\ \midrule
 ...........................
  vvv &  vvv & Insert correct user name \& gdfgfdg gfgfdgfgfgdfgdf fgfgfgd dfgfdgfg  \\\bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{longtable}
 \FloatBarrier


 \FloatBarrier
 \begin{longtable}[!ht]
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
 \caption[Test Cases for Admin Subsystem]{Test Cases for Admin Subsystem}
 \label{Test Cases for Admin Subsystem}\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
 \toprule
  \bfseries Test Objective/Scenario & \bfseries Function & \bfseries Input & \bfseries Expected Outcome\\ \midrule
  Create users  & Create a new user & Fill the text fields in user interface & Adding the user to database  \\ \midrule
  .....................
  Manage info.from re-insurance \& legal dept.  & Edit dept.info., functions  & Edit the text fields  & Editing the database \\\bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{longtable}
 \FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`longtable` and `tabularx` cannot be mixed this way. You should use either `tabularx` or `longtable` inside a `Table` enivironment.

Hoever, if you want to mix both properties try `tabu` package or older packages like `ltablex`.

Comment: yes,need to mixed this two.Because of long table and long rows.I try to used 'tabu' and 'ltabkex'.But this packages are cannot install.Give error 'Error response from server: 404'.What is a solution for "long table with long rows"?   thank u

Comment: The solution is to use a proper package like `tabu`. Find a book or manual and try to install packages. The error you mentioned may be solved by changing the server address.